# Поиск и замена чисел (из списка) в Notepad++

Tags: list, поиск, notepad++

Пытаюсь освоить "Блокнот++", простые операции худо-бедно получаются, а тут, четвёртый день бьюсь, - ничего не выходит. (видимо, - не моё это дело). Прошу совета-помощи у знающих людей.
Задача такая: Есть дюжина текстовых файлов по 5-7 тыс. строк, в них имеются строки типа:
"число"-текст.
Имеется список чисел (730 штук). Во всех файлах нужно найти и удалить все числа из списка с принадлежащим им текстом. Один раз я могу сделать это вручную, но если придется делать это несколько раз...
Notepad++ не позволяет макросу управлять окном "поиск-замена", или загнать туда переменную (либо я что-то делаю не так). Возможно надо как-то сопрягать Notepad c bat-файлом, но интернет говорит, что в bat как-то криво работают регулярные выражения.
Буду очень признателен, если кто подскажет несложный способ одолеть эту задачку (если такой существует)

Answer (score 2):

В Notepad++ макрос записывает и воспроизводит, в том числе, замены по регулярному выражению. Удаление делается заменой на пустую строку. Поэтому для одного файла Notepad++ решает задачу.
[image: окно замены notepad++]

Если же файлов много, то такая задача скорее для скрипта или bat файла.
В bat файлах нет регулярных выражений, но это обходится использованием внешних программ для командной строки - nhrt, sed и т.д. Соответственно, нужно прописать такое же удаление (замену на пустую строку) с помощью этих программ для определенных файлов, можно по маске.

Comment: _"Если же файлов много,"_ то есть кнопка "Заменить всё во всех открытых документах" ;)